# ScalaSpark: unable to create dataframe with scala-client dependency

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, couchbase

I need to support couchbase version 6 with spark 2.3 or 2.4 and scala version is 2.11.12. I am facing an issue while creating a data frame.

**SBT code snippet**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

resolvers += "Couchbase Snapshots" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.2"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.couchbase.client" %% "spark-connector" % "2.3.0",
  "com.couchbase.client" %% "scala-client" % "1.0.0-alpha.3")
```

**Code**

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Example")
      .master("local[*]") 
      .config("spark.couchbase.nodes", "10.12.12.88") // connect to Couchbase Server on localhost
      .config("spark.couchbase.username", "abcd") // with given credentials
      .config("spark.couchbase.password", "abcd")
      .config("spark.couchbase.bucket.beer-sample", "") // open the travel-sample bucket
      .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext
import com.couchbase.spark.sql._
val sql = spark.sqlContext
val dataframe = sql.read.couchbase()   
val result = dataframe.collect()
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.couchbase.client.core.message.CouchbaseRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

**Tried:**
As per the suggestion added a dependency

```
"com.couchbase.client" % "core-io" % "1.7.6",
```

Without scala-client dependency I am able to get dataframe but with scala-client unable to fix. please suggest a solution for this problem

Comment: Hi @meeti, how is your application packaged ? How do you submit it ? Obviously some dependency(/ies) is (/are) missing at runtime.

Comment: Could you share your assembly settings in the build.sbt?

Comment: @baitmbarek when I am tring to add "com.couchbase.client" %% "scala-client" % "1.0.0-alpha.3" then facing an issue. without this dependency I am able to get DF

Comment: @meetisharma hi, I'm the developer of the Couchbase scala-client.  It hasn't yet been tested with the Spark connector, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.  I'm not sure why you're seeing that error, it looks like a binary incompatibility.  Can you upgrade to Scala 2.12?  2.11 is pretty old now (2.13 is out, after all), and 2.12 will let you use the newest scala-client (beta.1, with GA coming very soon), and Spark Connector.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the changes to your build.sbt file and have added settings for the sbt-assembly plugin.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

resolvers += "Couchbase Snapshots" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.2"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "com.couchbase.client" %% "spark-connector" % "2.3.0")

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")       => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")   => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "reference.conf"                                 => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x: String if x.contains("UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case _                                                => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

You need to create a file called **plugins.sbt** in the directory called **project** and add the following line to it:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")
```

Once done, run the command `sbt clean compile assembly` in the projects' root directory. it should build your jar.

Comment: thanks @Yayati but you forgot to add "com.couchbase.client" %% "scala-client" % "1.0.0-alpha.3" dependency in code and after adding it getting the same exception as I mentioned in question description

Comment: @meetisharma i removed the client since the client is already brought in via the spark-couchbase connector. Follow the link on the official [documentation page](https://docs.couchbase.com/spark-connector/2.3/getting-started.html)

Comment: yes (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.couchbase.client/spark-connector_2.11/2.3.0) java-client is there but i have need of scala-client beacuse my code to fetch buckets and documents is written in scala.

Comment: The couchbase client would read the data as RDDs or Dataframes. All you have to do is mention the collection in the sparkconf